# Calling SOAP Action from .NET 6 HttpClient - Getting Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap, httpclient, .net-6.0

I need to call SOAP action based on specs that I have. I have already create the SOAP message and need to send it. I configured `HttpClient` but every time I send a post message I get Service Unavailable response status.

I have tested calling the SOAP service action from SOAPUI and it works. What am I missing in the `HttpClient`?

Here are the HTTP header specs from the service provider:

```
POST https://soap.msg-qa.com
HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=”UTF8”;action="QuoteRealTime" 
Content-Length: 3108
Host: soap.msg-qa.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5
```

Here is the code:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
              
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri("https://soap.msg-qa.com"),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post
                };

    request.Content = new StringContent(soapmessage, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

    request.Headers.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "QuoteRealTime");

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"result = {response.StatusCode}, message = {response.ReasonPhrase}");
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Success. result = {response.StatusCode}, message = {response.ReasonPhrase}");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: At least one thing seems to be wrong - you are adding content type header in 3 different ways and none of them adds the one you have used in the shown request - `application/soap+xml;charset=”UTF8”;action="QuoteRealTime"`

Comment: Any suggestion on how to add application/soap+xml;charset=”UTF8”;action="QuoteRealTime"

Comment: In the same way as you are adding text/xml...

Comment: Also you can generate client from wsdl and use it instead plain httpclient

Comment: Try something like `request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/soap+xml;charset=\"UTF8\";action=\"QuoteRealTime\"");` (remove other mentions where you are setting `text/xml`).

Comment: Made that change but same results. Service Unavailable.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing your own custom code you should look into the [dotnet-svcutil tool for .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide). It will generate C# code from a WSDL file, automatically handling all the gory details of SOAP for you. Then you'll use the generated client.

Here's how to generate a client for an actual (sample) web service on the command line.

```bash
dotnet svcutil --targetFramework net6.0 --namespace "*, ServiceReference" "https://apps.learnwebservices.com/services/hello?WSDL"
dotnet new classlib -f net6.0
dotnet add package System.ServiceModel.Http --version 6.1.0
rm Class1.cs
```

Comment: This is a bit complex since the message has to be signed and I need to get this done with my code since the proxy created by dotnet core will not do that.

Comment: You can extend the proxy with [custom behaviours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/configuring-and-extending-the-runtime-with-behaviors). Granted, this is rather complex.